# How to Apply threshold operator to highlight the largest object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I want to know how to apply threshold operator to highlight the largest object, which is the 3rd column of my output.

Using this code I am going to compare 3 images using `np.hstack()`. `img_hubble` is the original image, `dst` is the blurred image.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get image
img_hubble = cv2.imread("hubble.png", 0)

# define the kernel size
kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.float32)/225
dst = cv2.filter2D(img_hubble, -1, kernel)

#applying threshhold operator  to highlight the largest object
thresh = cv2.threshold(dst, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

result = np.hstack((img_hubble,dst,thresh))
cv2.imshow('result',thresh )

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output of the image below.

[image: Output]

Above code give me the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numerical tuple
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

Comment: cv2.threshold returns two things: the numerical threshold value AND the binary image as s tuple: thresh, binaryImage = cv2.threshold

Comment: @stateMachine thanks for the quick response. I am still unable to highlight the largest object in the image. Could you please help me?

Comment: I fixed your code so it is actually valid Python code, indentations matter. I also reorganized the text so that it doesn't start with code, I think it is easier to read and friendlier this way.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is, now that a comment has pointed out the source of your error. Please [edit] your post to fix the error and focus on the actual issue you're facing (you should *only* ever do this if there are not yet any answers posted!).

Comment: @DIlshanSandaruwan you are looking for the "**Largest Connected Component**", one way to do that through [labelling](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) and then finding the highest density label, please provide your input raw image.

Comment: cv2.imshow('result', result)

Comment: Hi Cris as shown in the image I should get the output. I got  output for mg_hubble and d st but I wasn't able to obtain  thresh image output. thresh image output is the largest object in the img_hubble image

Comment: @Bilal Hello Bilal, output of the image is given. I got output for mg_hubble and d st but I wasn't able to obtain thresh image output. thresh image output is the largest object in the img_hubble image

Comment: Add the input image to the question

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up the script and tried to solve what I believe your problem is.

Threshold returns 2 parameters, the threshold set, and the actual binary image:

```
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(dst, 0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Grabs the binary image while ignoring the threshold value.

Thresholding is only going to return a binary image where groups of bright pixels are kept. It will not return a single largest group of bright pixels.

Connected component or Labelling needs to be used for that. here is a solution:

```
# labels the threshold image and get stats.
n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)

# get areas from stats
areas = stats[:,-1]

# find the second largest area (Assuming the largest is always the background)
index_largest_component = np.argsort(areas)[-2]
cv2.imshow('result',(labels==index_largest_component).astype(np.float32))
```

This will filter your threshold image to only show the largest group of bright pixels.

All together the code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get image
img_hubble = cv2.imread("hubble.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# define the kernel size
kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.float32)/225
dst = cv2.filter2D(img_hubble, -1, kernel)

# applying threshhold operator  to highlight the largest object
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(dst, 0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# stack resulting images
result = np.hstack((img_hubble,dst,thresh))

# labels the threshold image and get stats.
n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)

# get areas from stats
areas = stats[:,-1]

# find the second largest area (Assuming the largest is always the background)
index_largest_component = np.argsort(areas)[-2]

# show stack and largest area
cv2.imshow('res',result)
cv2.imshow('result',(labels==index_largest_component).astype(np.float32))

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```